# Git add all files to a branch in bitbucket repo

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, git-branch

I'm going to add all newly added files from my local repo to bitbucket repo by using Git.First i move the head from master to my relevant branch by typing.

```
git checkout <branch>
```

But then when i type,

```
git add .
```

command nothing happens.How can i add all the newly added files from local to bitbucket?

Answer (score 3):

`git add .` will stage all new and modified files.

`git add -A` will stage all the files including the deleted ones(existing).

Commit your changes:

```
git commit -m <message>
```

You need to the push the changes to the remote repository

```
git push origin <branch>
```

In case, if you have not set up your remote repository. You can do it by:

```
git remote add origin <repo_url>
```

Comment: So i have already typed "git add ." as you have mentioned.But nothing happens.When i'm commiting to master,it works.But not for the branch.And i have set up my remote repository too.

Comment: which branch are you pushing? If you push master it will not push the changes in the other branch. Either you need to merge the branch to your master or you need to push the other branch to the remote repository (if required).

Comment: i want to add my new files to a already existing branch in bitbucket.so i moved the head to to that branch in bash.Then typed the git add command.

Comment: Make sure on which branch you have added the files. Suppose you want to push the changes to a branch named `master`. If the branch you have added new files is `master` then simply `git push origin master` should do the job. Otherwise you merge the other branch(which has the new files) to the master, by `git merge <other_branch>`, in your `master` branch. And then push the changes by `git push origin master`

Comment: Ok thanks.So if i merge the branch with master,will any issues occur?

Comment: You might get merge conflict which can be easily [resolved](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/). Also merging the branch to master depends on the way you are using git. Some people use `dev` or other branches to develop features and when the code seems stable they merge it to master. [Here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a good article on it.

Comment: Yes my branch is also develop.But i'm committing to others project.I forked it from them and doing the development.Once i finished the development i'm doing a pull request.So will it be any problem when they accept my pull request and merge the code?

Comment: And i could merge the branch and push the files.Thanks for that :)